# Android Push notifications for a specific time using Alarm Manager

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to use push notifications for a spesific time. I am using these codes;

This is my AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.arrrow_icon,
            "test", System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            NOTIFICATION_ID, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class),0);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String title = extras.getString("title");
    String note = extras.getString("note");
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, note, title, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, notification);

}
};
```

And this is my main class of part;

> Intent alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
>                         AlarmReceiver.class);
>                 alarmintent.putExtra("title", "test");
>                 alarmintent.putExtra("note", "test message");
>                 PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent
>                         .getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, alarmintent,
>                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
>                                         | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
>
> ```
>       AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
>           am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
> ```

If my application is working back push notifications are working correctly.but when I force close notifications do not working. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. First use this code for your alarm receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    NotificationManager nm;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Log Out !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//      Vibrator vibrator=(Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
//      vibrator.vibrate(1000);
        nm=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence ch="Log Out Service";
        CharSequence message="Log Out You have to login again!! ";
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    "You Are Logged out...", System.currentTimeMillis());
//       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
//                  new Intent(), 0);
         Intent notifyintent=new Intent(context,AlarmManagerTestActivity.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
            notifyintent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         notif.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, ch, message, pendingIntent);
                  nm.notify(0, notif);        
         }
    }
```

then put this code in your activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(your activity,AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
AlarmManagerTestActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer:)this is same result. it is working but when ı force stop application from apps menu ,notifications do not working

Answer (score 0):

ok then try to use this code,put this code out of onCreate() protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
        exitAppAnimate();
    }

```
private void exitAppAnimate() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager
            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 1
                && recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().indexOf(
                        getPackageName()) > -1) {
            // home button pressed
            IShomepressed = true;
            System.out.println("Home buttonpressed..........");

            // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            break;
        }
    }
}  and put this if (IShomepressed) {
        IShomepressed = false;
```

where you using Pending intent.this will help you.

Comment: Sorry ı could not understand .where must ı call  onUserLeaveHint()  function?.Thanks again

Comment: you should use onUserLeaveHint() method out side of onCreate() method.